# how to execute async func from a super class?

Tags: python, python-asyncio

will appreciate any help with the topic below.
there are two super classes from external packages: A and B.
the 3rd one class C is created by me

could be that there is a proper way to do it, workaround and another design patter.

Help is much appreciated.

```
import asyncio

#don't have control over this class

class A:

  def funcA (self):
    print ("Something from funcA")

  async def funcB (self):
    print ("Something from funcB")

#don't have control over this class

class B:

  def funcC (self):
    print ("Something from funcc")

  def funcD (self):
    self.funcC()
    print ("Something from funcD")

# my implementation and have full control

class C (B):

  def init (self):
    self.variablel = A()

    def funcE (self):
        self.variablel.funcB()

D=C()
D.funcE()
```

obviously when execute the following code I am getting the error: `RuntimeWarning: coroutine 'A.funcB' was never awaited`

Comment: Where's the async function?

Comment: Well, you'll need to await `funcB` then. What's the issue here?

Comment: async func is here

class A:

.....

  async def funcB (self):